# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Chemistry's [second moderator election](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Loong]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/flair/7951.png))</sub>
[image: orthocresol]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6536694631235584/0). Finally, OpaVote recently opened up their [recount feature](https://www.opavote.com/recount/6536694631235584/0) so that anyone can rerun the election and download the official ballot. (You can also try out a variety of counting methods, but we are sticking with Meek STV.)

Comment: Congrats guys!!

Comment: Congratulations to our newly-elected mods as well as all the candidates who ran a good race!

Comment: Woohoo. New mods . . . Now get to work.

Comment: Congratulations to the new overlords! Will there be bread and games? Just asking :D

Comment: @KlausWarzecha I want to eat cake.

Comment: Can the new mods do backflips?

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Many congratulations! Glad to have you both aboard!

Comment: Congrats to the new mods and to all the candidates. Let's keep up the good work and a great community! :-)

Comment: @Glorfindel I think I had more reputation and badges during that election.

Comment: @Loong I'm sure you're right - that's my script trying to fix broken images. Apparently the most recent Wayback Machine capture was too old ...

Comment: @Glorfindel I found it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20161012141908/https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/2

Answer (score 13):

Well done!

[image]

Master Loong and Orthocresol.

A hearty congratulations to both of you for being the community's choice to be the new mods.

You, guys, deserve this.

We all wish both of you to come out as one of the efficient mods in SE ;)

Along with your fellow comrades Mart and co., let you guys strive hard to maintain the quality and standard of Chem.SE.

Well done!

May the light of Chem.SE never be quelled!!

Comment: "...and co."?? ;)

Comment: Of course you and Manish ;)

Comment: @jonsca so much lol...

Comment: Too little, too late.

Answer (score 13):

I've been busy tonight, just got back, and am pretty tired, so I'll keep this short.

1. Regardless of who you voted for, thank you to all who participated in this election.
2. Thank you to the other candidates, who have raised a lot of good points during (and before) the election process - I look forward to having constructive meta discussions.
3. Thank you to Martin, jonsca and Manish, who have been doing an excellent job (most of it invisible to the average user).
4. Congratulations Loong. I mean, we never really had any doubt, did we? But congrats anyway.
5. Thank you for the well wishes to me, I appreciate it and it means a lot to me that people have faith in me to do well, with me being the obvious new kid on the block here. I will look to the other mods - and sometimes the community as well - for guidance.

Comment: I think the great news is that we have a great community with lots of active members. Hopefully this will continue to grow. :-)